# My computer will not boot from a usb

Tags: boot, usb, debian, installation, iso-image

I have a Toshiba Satellite computer and I am trying to boot it from a usb. I have made sure to put the usb in 1 on boot order and even tried the boot menu at the computers start up, but when I try to boot into the usb it acknowledges that the usb is there and formatted correctly, but after I click it it just shows a solid black screen for a few seconds and then boots into windows. I am using the ISO from this link: http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.5.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-8.5.0-amd64-netinst.iso 
Also I used the program Rufus to make the bootable usb and it still didn't work

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Will that usb drive boot on any other PC?

Comment: yes it worked fine on another laptop

Comment: Then it an issue with that particular PC, what is the make and model?

Comment: Toshiba Satellite E45t-B

Comment: Just try using other USB stick if you have! Some of them are not compatible and hence don't boot. I've faced this challenge on Samsung laptop with Kingston USB 3.0 flash drive

Answer (score 0):

Can you burn the ISO on to a DVD? If you can, just boot up from the DVD. I had the same problem and had to burn an ISO and boot W 10 from that. W 10 takes a long time to install, When it first initializes, it will show the W 10 logo for 5-10 minutes. After that, it will begin to install